# can any one tell me the details about below displayed control?can i arrange images on this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, controls, ui-design

**can any one tell me the details about  below displayed control?can i arrange images on this?**

Hi all,

may i know the name of below displayed control.

how can create this.

can i able to arrange images or text box inside the control.

Hi all,

can any one help me .

can any one provide me any code to create this ,sample apps or paths to refer.

i need to arrange images on to this.

is it possible to do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control you are looking at is a UIPickerView.  Apple documentation covers this pretty well.  It is possible to assign images to it.